# SQL column count does not match value count error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
    `m_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `p_id` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`m_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

and this insert

```
INSERT INTO `message` VALUES ('7');
```

and I am receiving a "column count does not match a row value count" error. It should work fine since the primary key is `auto_increment`.

Comment: your assumption in the closing sentence is not valid for MySQL, maybe for other DBMS's.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typically when you have an Auto Incrementing field you don't want to specify the value for that column. Which means you remove that value from the `VALUES`

However as Johan points out, whenever the number of columns in the table doesn't match the number of columns you must specify the column list on the target table.

Its good practice to do anyway in case the number of columns or column order changes

```
INSERT INTO 
message
(p_id)
Values ('7')
```

Comment: -1 @Conrad, You are saying you can get away with an insert like: insert into message values ('7') no I don't believe that will work in MySQL.

Comment: @Johan. I've updated my answer to be clear. When there's no AUTO_INCREMENT field the target Column names can be omitted.

Comment: the code shown will work, but note that this does not depend an a autoincrement column. If #of columns = #of inserted columns then MySQL is happy, regardless of autoincrement (y/n), keys (y/n) or whatever.

Comment: @Johan now I see what you mean. I wouldn't even think to specify the column when field is an auto_increment, which MySQL lets you do but SQL Server doesn't unless you SET INSERT_IDENTITY ON. I'll try and update the answer so it's sensible

Answer (score 10):

You must specify the column names when the number of values is not equal to the number of columns:

```
INSERT INTO message (p_id) VALUES ('7');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this

```
INSERT INTO `message` VALUES (NULL, '7');
```

This will match the number of columns and ignore the null insert into the auto increment id and insert the `auto increment` value;

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the columns you are inserting into.  If you do not the Database assumes the values you are providing are values for each column and in the exact order of the columns according to the schema.  Try the statement below.

```
INSERT INTO `message` (p_id) VALUES ('7');
```

In addition it is just good practice to always specify the columns in an insert statement. It helps for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `message` (p_id) VALUES ('7');
```

You're not specifying the columns, which there are 2 of, and trying to insert 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you do this

```
INSERT INTO message (p_id) VALUES ("7");
```